# How do I fix a 'No route matches' error when loading a flash burndown chart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

```rb
@graph = open_flash_chart_(880, 450,
                           url_for(:action => 'get_graph_data',
                                   :project_id => @project.id,
                                   :version_id => @version.id),
                           true)
```

I am creating a burndown chart but the chart is not visible showing the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"get_graph_data", :controller=>"version_burndown_charts", :project_id=>1, :version_id=>1}
```

Comment: Can you share your view, routes and which graph lib your are using?

Comment: It looks like your chart gem hits the path defined in your `url_for`. You need to ensure there's 1) a route in `config/routes.rb` for that URL and 2) a corresponding controller method (e.g., `VersionBurndownCharts#get_graph_data`).

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'projects/:project_id/Project', :controller => 'version_burndown_charts', :action => 'index'
    post 'projects/:project_id/version_burndown_charts/:id', :controller => 'version_burndown_charts', :action => 'show'

end